# SpringBoot Test - possible to run tests against the default application context?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, junit, integration

Execution of the JUnit test of a Spring Boot application causes a testing context of the application to be started whenever the test is invoked.  Is there a way to run this test against a spring boot application that has already started without having to spin up a second application context for the test?  For example, can the testing framework be instructed to use an existing application context that has already been launched?

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyAppTests {

    @Autowired
    public SomeService someService;

    @Test
    public void testInjection() throws AssertionError {
        Assert.assertTrue(someService != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to test. Just forget about for a moment you are using spring boot. Do you want to test against real application that is already running and treating it as blackbox or do you want to test some slices of the real application by replacing some parts with mocks or stubs?

Comment: I want to periodically run api tests against the container from within the container service, e.g. by a rest controller bound to a URL like /execute-all-api-tests that would return a 200 response on success or an error on failure which could then be integrated with web monitoring to detect when the API is not functioning properly.  These are basically integration tests that are running in an operational context.

Answer (score 1):

There is **No** way to run tests just using an already started application context, meanwhile without launching a second testing application, if on the premise that you describe.

It means JUnit test of a Spring Boot application is a kind of whitebox testing, the test case will only runs in the environment which is started by itself. The test case has nothing to do with other already running application context.

However, if you really want to run tests against a spring boot application (just like a running test environment) that has already started, maybe you could try some other blackbox testing, for example, API testing or GUI testing. But it will not allow you test `SomeService` class directly.

Comment: Yeah, I will probably transition to that approach - although I like the JUnit interface in the spring tool suite to quickly run and view the results of integration tests so I was hoping to be able to continue to use the JUnit framework to run those tests.  Not sure if that's still possible - in order to get dependency injection in the test class to inspect the configuration, I had to use annotations that pulled in the rest of the spring testing framework.  Maybe there's a simple solution to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Update you test class as below and it should fix your problem.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = YourApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT)
public class MyAppTests {
```

Comment: This didn't work. After spending a lot of time on this problem, I'm pretty sure that Peter Quan is correct that there is not a way to run spring tests against an active (non-test) container.  I had pursued the possibility of overwriting the location of the web application context used by the test environment to force it to use a running container which would already be cached (which presumably would do something similar to what you have suggested with profiles) - but spring boot uses a DB to store configurations by default.  I will just have to settle for a second container for now.